# mysql is showing error in the syntax

Tags: python, mysql

I am having trouble in executing this query in python. I have an IP database which has 3 column startip, endip and country. Now I want to the location of the ip. this is my code

```
def get_country(ip):

    try:
            conn = MySQLConnection(host='localhost', database='ipdb', user ='root', password='password')
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            query = 'SELECT * FROM db6 WHERE %s BETWEEN INET_ATON(startip) AND INET_ATON(endip)'
            ip_inint= ip2int(ip)
            cursor.execute(query,ip_inint)
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            while row is not None:
                    print " Start range %s end range %s country %s " %(row[0], row[1], row[2])
                    row = cursor.fetchone()
    except Error as error:
            print(error)
```

ip2int function is

```
def ip2int(addr):
    return struct.unpack("!I", socket.inet_aton(addr))[0]
```

error i am receiving is

```
1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s BETWEEN INET_ATON(startip) AND INET_ATON(endip)' at line 1
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: what is %s indented to be???

Comment: what is %s supposed to mean here? at that place you need a column name or similar?

Comment: You also need backticks ( ` ) around your table name

Comment: i an passing ip_inint in query in this line
cursor.execute(query,ip_inint)
isn't this how we are supposed to pass value to mysql.
like they have done [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html)

Comment: @heinst I didn't understand what are you telling. Please elaborate. where is (') missing?

Comment: put backticks around db6

Comment: well I did  'SELECT * FROM db6' ' WHERE %d BETWEEN INET_ATON(startip) AND INET_ATON(endip)' 


is it correct? the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a *tuple* to `execute()`:

```
cursor.execute(query, (ip_inint,))
```

A list will probably work too:

```
cursor.execute(query, [ip_inint])
```

An alternative is to use a dictionary with named variables in the query:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM db6 WHERE %(ip_inint)s BETWEEN INET_ATON(startip) AND INET_ATON(endip)'
cursor.execute(query, {'ip_inint': ip_inint})
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: I tried your solution, but it is showing " Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement " when i used cursor.execute(query, (ip_inint,)) or cursor.execute(query, [ip_inint]).  Last solution worked. Thanks